# How to check if an image is pressed pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a cookie clicker clone, but my code can't detect when the grandma button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cookie Clicker')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
cookie = pygame.image.load('cookie.png')
grandma = pygame.image.load('grandma.png')
cookies = 0

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(cookie, (x,y))

def grandshop(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(grandma, (xx,yy))

x =  0
y = 0
xx = 450
yy = 20

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if cookie.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                if event.button == 1:
                    
                    cookies += 1
                    pygame.display.set_caption(f'Cookies: {cookies}')
                else:
                    break
            if grandma.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                print("It actually worked! :)")

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x,y)
    grandshop(xx,yy)
        
    pygame.display.update()
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I had expected it to print out "It actually worked! :)" when the grandma image was clicked.

Comment: Check out the edited question clicking on 'edited' to see how it was done that it shows up the right way. P.S. use triple backticks to enclose code as it is to be shown as code. Else indenting by 4 spaces makes the text to appear as code.

Comment: The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has a `.pos` attribute which is the x, y coordinates of the button press, so you needn't call `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. Before  you get too complicated, you should look at [pygame sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), they make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change appropriate lines in your code to:

```
if cookie.get_rect(topleft=(x,y)).collidepoint(mouse_pos):
```

and

```
if grandma.get_rect(topleft=(xx,yy)).collidepoint(mouse_pos):
```

The `.get_rect()` method called without parameter gives you the rectangle of the loaded image with the left upper corner set to (0, 0) and not to the actual position of the image on the screen. This was the reason why a click on `cookie` was also hconsidered to be a click on `grandma` and a click on `grandma` gave `False` as result of `.collidepoint()`.

The `.get_rect()` method allows passing of a keyword parameter to obtain the rectangle coordinates of the rectangle moved to a with (x,y) specified screen position. The keyword used for this purpose in the code above is `,topleft=(xx,yy)`. Another known to me keyword parameter allowed in `.get_rect()` are `center` and `bottomright`.